# Checking regression model

Tags: regression, correlation

I am trying to play around with some data that I have got. Specifically, I have gathered data from an online database, which contain the following parameters: A can be (1,2,3,4,5), B and C which they can take all the real numbers. Now, the downloaded data include 9300 mutual funds and the parameters A,B and C symbolise ESG rating (Environmental, social and corporate governance), Volatility (standard deviation), and Returns, respectively. What I want to find out is if there is a visible pattern between the ESG rating/volatility or ESG rating/return amongst these mutual funds. 
Because 9300 mutual funds are a lot, I decided to group them by sector and then use the average (A,B,C) from each sector. So I created 120 sectors by following this method.

```
**Sector                ESG Rating  Std Dev Total Ret YTD**
Corporate Bond          3.44        4.08    3.73
Sector Equity Other     3.42        18.81   3.62
Sector Equity Utilities 3.33        14.70   3.37
EUR Corporate Bond      3.05        4.04    3.00
Emerging Markets Alloc  2.75        13.68   2.89
US L-C Value Equity     3.13        17.22   2.82
Property                3.38        16.21   2.74
EMEA Equity             2.75        19.15   2.39
```

But, apparently the charts that I generated on excel, even-though they make sense, are not optimal to identify any pasterns. 
The problem as you can see from the pics bellow lies within the fact that the average ranking of each sector is close to 3, which is also the median value from the ESG ranking. Is there another way to check for any possible patterns as I aforementioned?

The reason I posted this novice question here is not to get a free answer for a task. Although I do work in finance, this is a personal question; I am not looking for a solution or to take advantage of the forum. But I do look to gain a wider perspective of how to manipulate data. Anyhow, whoever feels interested and wants to contribute please feel welcome.

Thank you very much.

[image: ESG rating/return]

[image: ESG rating/volatility]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing right now is simply eyeballing (looking) at the data. It's fairly difficult for a human to see any patterns.

Instead of physically looking at the data with a graph, you should try running a linear regression on the data. This will allow a computer to find patterns. If you'd like to stick with Excel, Excel has an add-in called 'Data Analysis' which includes a linear regression module. You can run a linear regression with

$$ Y = aX_1+bX_2+c
$$
where
$Y =$ Returns, $X_1 =$ ESG Rating, $X_2 = $ Standard Deviation

Once you've done that, you can look at the results to see if there are any statistically significant results. If you don't know how to interpret the results, ask here!

Comment: Thanks for the tip Kontorus. I will try to see if I find any interesting results. Appreciate your response.